# Segmentation fault (core dumped) declaracion arrays

Tags: c

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que tengo que simular un minishell que ejecute mandatos en c. 
A la hora de declarar el array donde iran los pids de los hijos y los pipes creados, me da un Segmentation fault (core dumped), cualquiera de las dos lineas a continuacion da el error.

```
int hijos[mandatos];
```

```
int *pipes[mandatos-1];
```

`mandatos` es una variable que tiene el numero de mandatos. Por ejemplo en el caso de ejecutar `ls | ls` seria dos. He intenado meter enteros en vez de la variable, y funciona hasta los valores  `int hijos[5];` `int *pipes[4];` cualquier valor por encima da el mismo error ya mencionado.

Los arrays no se utilizan en ninguna otra parte del codigo de momento, asi que el problema esta ahí.

De la misma menera:

```
char *s1="prompt=msh ";
putenv(s1);
```

Da el error de segmentation fault tambien...

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Realmente estás programando en C#? Se me hace raro que uses punteros en C# (es un lenguaje de alto nivel). Puede que estés usando lenguaje C.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon del mundo, perdon, efectivamente el lenguaje es C.

Comment: Esas dos líneas que agregaste arriba no es suficiente para detectar el error. Deberías de añadir el código donde uses las variables `hijos` y `pipes`.

Comment: Lo primero agradecerte la respuesta @MrDave1999,  el error salta al inicializarlas, no llego a usarlas mas alla que esas dos lineas.

Comment: char *s1="prompt=msh> ";    putenv(s1); da tambien el error de segmentation fault...

Comment: Pon todo el código

Comment: @julenperez Si pero no veo el posible segment-fault. Este tipo de error es ocasionado cuando se intenta acceder a una dirección que el programa no tiene acceso. Por ejemplo: `int* x = (int*)0x001; *x = 9;`. Tu código lo he probado y no me da ningún error...

Comment: Hace falta que subas más código, sobre todo de cómo defines esos dos arrays, y cómo los usas, pero tiene pinta de que estás saliéndote de los rangos de los arrays.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, efectivamente teniais razon y el error estaba en otra parte... lo siento y gracias de nuevo